# recursive tables in html

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to display a recursive table in html for a testing database, and to do this I currently use divs and the table/table-row/table-row-group CSS display attributes. This doesn't work for more than 1 level of recursion, as my code looks like :

> table
>
> > table row
> >
> > table-row-group
> >
> > > table-row-group
> > >
> > > > table-row

The last table-row doesn't count as a row of the first table, as I imagine the element whose display attribute is table-row-group needs to be a direct child of the initial table. How could I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a table, if the data you're trying to use is tabular, it's the best option.

Comment: I use recursive views and for that I need divs to branch my views into. Tables cannot have divs inside them :(

Comment: Why can't you use DIVs inside a table? You can have DIVs inside a table `td`

Comment: inside rows only, and I would like my views to be able to create multiple rows. If a view is inside a div that is contained in a row, this view can only create one row.

Comment: Why not create a new `tbody`?

Comment: Where did you get in the end?

Comment: For whatever reason I couldn't get tbody to work with my javascript code, so I only used display:table for the div that contains the table, and display:table-cell for every cell, without using table-rows or anything. It worked out :) Thanks again.